# Identifying which tests provide coverage in VS2010 code coverage results

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

Does anyone know of an easy way to work backwards from the VS2010 code coverage in-file highlighting to the test that provides the coverage? I have a file with one method covered and another not but looking through my tests I can't spot the one providing the current coverage. It would be great to be able to navigate back from the code highlighting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test coverage information is mostly boolean data which has been OR'd together.
When you execute test A, and probe location P is hit, tools remember that
P has been executed. If you execute test B, and the same probe location P gets
hits, the tool remembers that P has been executed.  So  coverage(P)=executedby(A) OR executed(B).

The good news is you get coverage data.  The bad news is that you cannot distinguish
by looking at coverage(P) whether A or B caused it.

Your only real option is to run each test separately and record the results.

Comment: If you can run the entire set of tests from a script, then you can make a script that runs the tests individually.